# Be able to use angular-filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-filters

I'm having some issues when I try to use angular-filter:

I've imported these links in the HTML file:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.11/angular-filter.min.js"></script>
```

I've added the module in my js file:

```
var app = angular.module('angularPrueba',[angular.filter]);
```

I'm having these error:

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=angularPrueba&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.2.22%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dundefined%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255Bng%253Aareq%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.2.22%252Fng%252Fareq%253Fp0%253Dmodule%2526p1%253Dnot%252520a%252520function%25252C%252520got%252520undefined%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.2.22%252Fangular.min.js%253A6%253A450%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Db%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.2.22%252Fangular.min.js%253A18%253A497)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520Va%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.2.22%252Fangular.min.js%253A19%253A78)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.2.22%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A404%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520r%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.2.22%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A290)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520e%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.2.22%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A148)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.2.22%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A225%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520r%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.2.22%252Fangular.min.js%253A7%253A290)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520e%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.2.22%252Fangular.min.js%253A33%253A148)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520gc%2520(https%253A%252F%252Fajax.googleapis.com%252Fajax%252Flibs%252Fangularjs%252F1.2.22%252Fangular.min.js%253A36%253A252)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js:6:450%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js:34:28%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js:7:290)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20e%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js:33:148)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js:33:225%0A%20%20%20%20at%20r%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js:7:290)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20e%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js:33:148)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20gc%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js:36:252)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js:18:60)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20fc%20(https:%2F%2Fajax.googleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.22%2Fangular.min.js:18:277

Comment: try var app = angular.module('angularPrueba',['filters']);

Comment: and use filters like - var module = angular.module('filters', []);

module.filter('capitalize', function () {
    return function (input) {
        if (input == 'N/A'){
            return input;
        }else{
            return (!!input) ? input.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + input.substr(1).toLowerCase() : '';
        }
        
    }
});

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which 'angular-filter' library you're using, but you have to add module dependencies as the *string name of the module you're adding as a dependency*.

So if the main module name of the 'angular-filter' library is `angular.filter`, you should add that as a string:

```
var app = angular.module('angularPrueba',['angular.filter']);
```

If you don't know the name of the module,  check the library's website or check the sourcecode of it.

Comment: @dr3w31 You're welcome, if my answer solved your problem you can always upvote and/or mark it as accepted